# Редирект с под домена на домен если нет под домена?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Помогите разобраться что к чему?

Если пользователь набрал http://petro.mysite.ru как ему показать страницу user.php?u=petro которая располагается по адресу http://mysite.ru/user.php но при этом чтобы в его строке так и осталось petro.mysite.ru  Еще дело в том, что под домена petro не существует.

Можно ли как то такое провернуть?

Comment: гуглите в сторону "динамических поддоменов"

Answer (score 1):

Если нет поддомена - то и редирект через htaccess или header ты сделать не сможешь.В любом случаи, поддомен сделать очень легко.(В панели управления хостинга, либо на сайте, где этот домен покупал)

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность настройки DNS:

1. В настройках DNS домена добавляем wildcard (*.example.com), чтобы любой поддомен шел на основной
2. Используем mod_rewrite и пишем правило. Либо разбираем глобальную переменную `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Есть достаточно много ссылок по данной теме, как уже указали в комментарии. Например [вот здесь](https://habr.com/post/101585/) правила предлагаются, правда для nginx, но думаю можно по аналогии и для апача написать.